# Can I pass an object literal with properties to children in Angular template?

Tags: angular, typescript

Can I have something like this in Angular templates?

`<some-item *ngFor="let section of x.Sections"
    [item]="{'cols': section.Width, 'rows': section.Height, 'x': section.OX, 'y': section.OY}">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely you can.

...oh, I need more characters for my answer to be accepted.